# App crashes in Blackberry os7

Tags: blackberry-webworks

My app developed with Blackberry webworks v 2.1.1 was working fine in OS6 simulator and device(Blackberry Torch 9800).But crashing every time with OS 7 simulator(Blackberry Torch 9810,Blackberry Bold 9930) while navigating from one page to other page.I am using html and java script and also using jquery 1.6.4 min.js.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried upgrading to the latest version of the Webworks SDK (v 2.3.1)?